# generate a dependency tree of the inheritance hierarchy

Tags: python, inheritance, recursion

i am trying to write a recursive algorithm to generate a dependency tree of the inheritance hierarchy of a class. Below is my sample code. The problem i am getting is when we the elements in the bases list are more than one, only the 1st element of the list and its parent classes are printed.

```
def get_bases(klass):
   bases = getattr(klass, '__bases__')
   if len(bases) == 0:
      return None
   else:
      for item in bases:
        print item
        return  get_bases(item)
```

I also would like to generate some kind of graph showing the inheritance hierarchy. Kindly help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for item in bases:
    print item
    return get_bases(item)
```

You recurse into the item, and then immediately return *without continuing through the for loop*. You can replace with something like:

```
for item in bases:
    print item
    get_bases(item)
```

or you could perhaps build up a tree structure instead for printing later (pprint_node shows one possible implementation):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, item, children):
        self.item = item
        self.children = children

def get_class_tree(klass):
    bases = getattr(klass, '__bases__')
    return Node(klass, [get_class_tree(item) for item in bases])

def pprint_node(node, level=0):
    print ("  "*level) + str(node.item)
    for child in node.children:
        pprint_node(child, level+1)
```

Comment: thanks @Owen, i hope 'def Node' supposed to be 'class Node' after running the get_class_tree method, how do i print out the tree structure generated by this method?

Comment: Yes, it should be class. Fixed. Also added a very simple printing method you could start with.